# write five digits numbers using $0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

It is given that we want to write five digits numbers using $0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4$.

How many ways are there to write it $?$

**My thought** In the first place, it seems cumbersome question a little bit , because i think that we should write them separately in terms of the leading term such that firstly i check over $1$ as leading term , then $2$ so on. However , this process is exhaustive and i hope to find  elegant approach for this question.

Comment: Try answering the question if we had an unlimited supply of $0$'s, $1$'s, $2$'s, etc...  Now, how many of those were "bad" because we used too many of something?  Could they have been "bad" for more than one reason?

Comment: are there any additional restrictions like does using one number remove it from choices?

Comment: @user29418 the question does not have any restriction, it is just what is written

Comment: JMoravitz's solution should be the most efficient given none of them is less than two numbers. So all bad cases will be disjoint cases. So it should be easy to subtract them.

Comment: @MathLover but many start with zero and technically they are not 5 digits numbers

Comment: @Raffaele you are right. I wrote them as separate cases but the answer I wrote here, $2720$ includes one's with trailing zeroes.

Comment: @MathLover I counted $2147$ five digits numbers

Comment: @Raffaele that seems correct to me. At least I get the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method which still requires a bit of work, but which is still more efficient then naive brute force.

Start with a simpler question:

> For each $k=1,2,\dots,5$, how many $k$ digit numbers can you make using $3, 3, 4, 4, 4$?

With a little work, the answers are

| k | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # numberss with k digits using 3s and 4s | 2 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 10 |

Next....

> For each $k=1,2,\dots,5$, how many $k$ digit numbers can you make using $2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4$?

The key is that we can leverage or work in the previous step to make this one easier. Take the summation of all ways to place the $2$'s, times the number of ways to fill in the rest of the empty spaces with $3$'s and $4$'s, the latter of which can be looked up in the previous table. For example,

\begin{align}
\text{# $5$-digit nums with $2$'s, $3$'s and $4$'s} 
&= \binom{5}0\cdot \hspace{-1cm}
\overbrace{10}^\text{# 5 digit nums with 3,4}\hspace{-.1cm}
+ \binom{5}1\cdot \hspace{-1cm}\overbrace{10}^\text{# 4 digit nums with 3,4}\hspace{-1cm}
\\
&+ \binom{5}2\cdot \hspace{-1cm}\underbrace{7}_{\substack{\;\\\\\text{# 3 digit nums with 3,4}}}\hspace{-.1cm}
+ \binom{5}3\cdot \hspace{-1cm}\underbrace{4}_\text{# 2 digit nums with 3,4}\hspace{-.1cm}
\\&+ \binom{5}4\cdot \hspace{-1cm}\underbrace{2}_{\substack{\;\\\\\text{# 1 digit nums with 3,4}}}\hspace{-1cm}
\hspace{1.5cm}=\boxed{180}
\end{align}
You then have to do the same for the $1,2,\dots,4$ digit numbers, giving another row to the table. Then, use that row to calculate the number of numbers where you can use digits $1$ to $4$.

| k | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # numbers with k digits using 3s and 4s | 1 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 10 |
| # numbers with k digits using 2, 3, and 4 | 1 | 3 | 9 | 26 | 71 | 180 |
| # numbers with k digits using 1, 2, 3 and 4 | 1 | 4 | 16 | 62 | 229 | 795 |

Finally, the number of five digit numbers using all available digits is found by summing over all ways to place the zeroes, times the number of ways to fill what remains with $1$ to $4$, which is in the last row of the table:
$$
\binom{4}0\cdot 795+\binom{4}1\cdot 229+\binom{4}2\cdot 62+\binom{4}3\cdot 16=\boxed{2147}
$$

Comment: (+1) This is just amazing!

Comment: thanks for your works :)

Answer (score 4):

Digits given: $0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4$ and we need to make five digit numbers from them. Removing bad cases seems to be a good choice here, even though there is a bit more work in the end for removing numbers with leading zeroes. The point to note is that you do not have any overlap between bad cases of two numbers or more, on other words, we cannot simultaneously have bad cases for two of them.

Number of bad cases for $0$ or $3 = \underbrace{5 \cdot 4}_{\text{Four 0's}} + \underbrace{1}_{\text{Five 0's}} = 21$

Number of bad cases for $1$ or $4 = {5 \choose 3} \cdot 4^2 + 5 \cdot 4 + 1 = 181$

Number of bad cases for $2 = 1$

Total number of bad cases $ = 2 \times 21 + 2 \times 181 + 1 = 405$

Subtract this from total number of unrestricted cases $ = 5^5 = 3125$ (if we had $5$ choices for each digit). **That gives us an answer of $2720$.**

Now as we need proper $5$ digit numbers where leading zeroes are not allowed,

**Numbers with leading zeroes $ = 5^4$**. Out of which below are already counted in above bad cases -

In bad cases for $0$, only $4$ start with another digit so $17$ duplicates.

In bad cases for $3$, numbers with leading zeros $ = 1$ (fix first digit as $0$, then remaining four digits are all $3$).

In bad cases for $1$ (or $4$), numbers with leading zeroes $ = 4 \cdot 4 + 1 = 17$ (first digit $0$, choose three out of four remaining digits as $1$ and the last remaining digit other than $1$ or all four digits as $1$).

So total five digit numbers without leading zeroes $ = 2720 - 5^4 + 52 = 2147$

Comment: I didn't understand the second part. Is it trailing zeros or leading zeros?

Comment: @cosmo5 thanks for the callout. I am surprised with myself that I wrote _trailing_  $6$ times without realizing I was writing _trailing_ instead of _leading_ :)

Comment: Yes, now I understand.

Comment: thanks for your works :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Can you please tell me which case is accounted for with ${5 \choose 3} \  4^2$ in para 3? @Math_Lover

Comment: @Shub I assume you are referring to ${5 \choose 3} \cdot 4^2 + 5 \cdot 4 + 1$. The first term is where $0$ (also same for $4$) appears three times in five digits. We choose three out of five spaces for $0$ and then we have four choices for each of the remaining two spaces each  from $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ . That is why ${5 \choose 3} \cdot 4^2$