# Truncated permutations with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'd like to know if there is a general formula or technique for this type of problems, which I describe generally as follows :

> Say you have $n$ different colors and that you have $r_1$ balls of the first color, $r_2$ balls of the second color,..., $r_n$ balls of the $n$-th color. How many different sequences of $p$ balls, with $p < \sum_{k=1}^n r_k$ , are there?

It seems to me that it is not easy to calculate the number of different sequences.

In the case $p = \sum_{k=1}^n r_k$ it becomes a permutation with repetition problem because the total number is  $\frac{p!}{r_1!r_2! \dots r_n!} $.

However,  with $p < \sum_{k=1}^n r_k$ is trickier . How can it be done?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007716/permutation-problem-select-m-objects-from-n-ones-of-r-types-by-sampling-without?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the Linked Questions there, for more discussion.