# Permutation - how to order 6 elements out of 13 with 3 conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

```
Elements = [
A, A, 
A, A,
B, B, B,
W, W, W, W, W, W ]
```

**Slots**: `_ _ _ _ _ _`

**Conditions**:

- *There must always be at least one 'W' in one of the 6 slots*
- A's must always come in pairs (AA)
- B's must always come in  threes (BBB)

**Example**: AAWBBB

---

I know about the `n! / (n-r)!` formula. But I am unsure of what to do, in order to implement the grouping of AA and BBB, and the condition of having at least one W.

I am pretty sure that the result is 22 different permutations, after enumerating with pen/paper - but I can't explain the math behind.

Can anyone clarify if these are permutations or combinations, I am still confused about that.

---

Edit: I've now written down the 22 permutations, so you can see the result:

```
W W W W W W
A A W W W W
W A A W W W
W W A A W W
W W W A A W
W W W W A A
A A A A W W
A A W A A W
A A W W A A
W A A A A W
W A A W A A
W W A A A A
B B B W W W
W B B B W W
W W B B B W
W W W B B B
B B B A A W
B B B W A A
W B B B A A
A A B B B W
A A W B B B
W A A B B B
```

Comment: Have you tried counting the number of permutations/combinations in which there are *exactly* $k$ 'W's and compute the sum from $k=1$ to $k=6$?

Comment: You missed W B B B A A

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I've edited the question now

Comment: "Can you clarify if these are permutations or combinations?" They are neither. Not everything is a permutation or combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time thinking about this, I came up with the idea of splitting this up into 5 cases. There are 5 different possible amounts of A, B & W.

1. A x 0, B x 0, W x 6
2. A x 2, B x 0, W x 4
3. A x 4, B x 0, W x 2
4. A x 0, B x 3, W x 3
5. A x 2, B x 3, W x 1

With this in mind, we can add the result of each case, in order to get to the final result.

1. `1!          = 1` # Every slot only has one possible value
2. `5!/4!       = 5` # There are 5 elements in total: 4xW and a group of 2xA. And I divide by 4! because there are 4 repeated elements
3. `(4!/2!) / 2 = 6` # 4 elements in total: 2xW and two groups of 2xA. In the end we take half of that, or else the two groups of 2xA will *flip* positions, and we will have twice the permutations. If this step can be done prettier, please speak up.
4. `4!/3!       = 4` 4 elements in total: 3xW and a group of 3xB
5. `3!          = 6` 3 elements in total: 1xW, a group of 2xA and a group of 3xB

SUM             = 22

Comment: please use mathjax to render math.  This is not a programming site.

Comment: @amWhy Did you seriously downvote a correct answer, because it doesn't make use of a 3rd party renderer? I'd like to know where that is stated as a requirement?!

Comment: Now I just did.  Was it worth it to verbally attack me like that?  Accusing innocent people is just not appropriate.  Now who next are you going to accuse as giving you your first downvote?

Comment: @amWhy So now you downvoted because of some personal agenda?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a recursion by thinking what the first letter will be. Let's denote

$$c(n, a, b, w) = \text{number  of words of length n when can use a A's, b B's and w W's and following the given rules}$$

We have of course $c(n, a, b, w) = 0$ if any of the parameters is negative. And  $c(0, a, b, w) = 1$ when $a,b,w \geq 0$. Then the recursion: The first letter can be either $w$ in which case you use up one W and the rest of the word is a word of length $n-1$ following the rules with one less W do use. If the first letter is an A the you must have another A following it and then the rest $n-2$ letters form a word with 2 fewer A's to use. Similarly you might have BBB in the beginning and then an $n-3$-word. All together

$$c(n, a,b,w) = c(n-1, a,b,w-1) + c(n-2, a-2,b,w) + c(n-3, a,b-3, w)$$

These are a bit cumbersome to tabulate because of the 4 parameters but it's ease to code up and indeed you get $c(6,4,3,6) = 22$.

For the nomenclature, I would just call these words with the letters $\{A, B, W\}$ They are more like permutations because the order matters but there can be repeated things and not every thing needs to be there so they are like, I guess you could call them partial permutations of a multiset.

Another way to calculate is with generating functions. We have three types of objects: W, AA and BBB. But because these have different lengths, we must weight them as $z, z^2$ and $z^3$. I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105490/formula-for-r-permutations-of-a-multiset) where formula is given (but each element is a single element, no blocks AA, BBB like here). I tried to implement it with SageMath but it doesn't work :(

```
#This is the recursion formula
def c(n, a, b, w):
    if any(t<0 for t in (n,a,b,w)): return 0
    if n==0: return 1
    return c(n-1,a,b,w-1) + c(n-2,a-2,b,w) + c(n-3,a,b-3,w)

print(c(6,4,3,6))


#Let's try with generating function
def multiCulti(n, a,b,w):
    R.<z> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 1)
    p = product(sum(z^(t*j)/factorial(j) for j in range(s+1)) for t,s in zip((1,2,3), (w, a//2, b//3)))
    return factorial(n)*p.coefficient({z: n})

print(multiCulti(6, 4,3,6))
```

Can someone spot the error or doesn't the weighting of block lenghts work like that?

**EDIT:** I think I now understand why it doesn't work. You should divide by the ways you can reorder among the blocks. But this can't be done like in alltogether in the end since you don't know how many there are of each sort. The $n$ thinks you have $6$ objects but in reality you might have fewer if there are AA's or BBB's. So that $n!$ is wrong! But if we introduce two other variables $z_A$ and $z_B$ to count how many AA's and BBB's appear...

Comment: I forgot about the rule that there must be at least one W. That might complicate things but in this particular case a word without W can't be formed following the other rules. (This is because you don't have enough of B's to do BBBBBB and not enought A's to do AAAAAA and if you put BBB only one AA fits and W is forced.)

Comment: I guess you could encode the one necessary W rule into the generating function if we get it to work at all anyhow?

Comment: And in the recursion you could introduce yet another parameter telling if we have used a W already and then modify the recursion accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am no math genius, and I have some trouble understanding your explanation. This is the first time I've come across this stackexchange, so please bare with me. However - I have come to a solution myself, and I will post it in here later today.

Comment: No problem. Although I didn't in fact solve it in the general case (the rule "at least one W" is missing from the recursion and the generating function didn't work at all :D). Great that you solved it! Does your solution work in the general case i.e. with any amount of available A,B and W's?